# How can I pack the application to get a single .exe for Win or .app for Mac?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm trying to evaluate electron (http://electron.atom.io/) for our needs which are as follows:

- OS X and Windows desktops platforms support
- ability to launch local external executable (our installer)
- support a rich UI, at least image background, image buttons, retina display etc.
  The result should be a **nice** wrapper to our installation program (which will run in silent mode).

So, the first question:
Is the **electron** is the right technology to support the minimal requirements above?

If yes, where can I find the example how to run the local executable? I was unable to find one....

And how can I pack the application to get a single .exe for Win or .app for Mac? I looked in electron distribution documentation, but was unable to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to make an exe file for mac:

```
electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=darwin
```

For windows :

```
  electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=win32
```

Just run this command on CMD outside your source directory.

Comment: I installed electron-packager globally, but when I run this command on windows I get these errors: Unable to determine undefined. Please specify an undefined

For more information, please see
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#undefined

Unable to determine Electron version. Please specify an Electron version

For more information, please see
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#version

Comment: Sorry for windows is electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=win32.
I will update my answer

Comment: Install electron globally and locally as well

Comment: thanks, I managed to run it on windows, but I got folder with all files (bundle). I'm looking to how can I create a single .exe? Like if you download slack installer for example.

Comment: Go inside the folder and do you see your application . Just double click that application to run it that is your exe app

Comment: yeah, I noticed the exe inside the folder. I just need to distribute the final product as one single executable (not zip).

Comment: Yeah just take that exe file outside the folder. And do whatever you want with it. That is the desktop app.

Comment: really? I tried, but it looks for node.dll, ffmpeg.dll and others, so I'm not sure it's just that simple - taking the .exe and run it elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You're not thinking along the right axis. Both Electron and other cross-platform UI tooklits (such as wxWidgets, GTK or QT) meet your requirements.

More relevant differences:

- Electron uses HTML, CSS and Javascript. If you're familiar with these technologies, your development process will be faster. The alternatives are harder to use, with the usual modern developer skill set.
- Electron is heavier and slower than the alternatives. This means a larger download and poor performance on low-end machines. For a small installer, it may be overkill.

As for your 2nd question, you can bundle your application using [ElectronPackager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager).

Answer (score 1):

I, too have evaluated electron and find it to be fairly easy to work with. As you know it does boast being cross platform, basically due to it's nature of running a version of chrome for the desktop.

Based on your requirements, I would give electron a good look. If you know basic web development, then learning electron will not be too difficult.

One of the ways I took to learning more about electron was to clone an electron project off of GitHub. The project is called mongotron and it can be cloned from [Here](https://github.com/officert/mongotron.git).

In this project, the developer uses gulp to build the code. He uses gulp, with electron packager to build the various outputs. For instance to build an OS-X version the command would be:

```
gulp.task('release-osx', ['pre-release'], (next) => {
  electronPackager(_.extend(RELEASE_SETTINGS, {
    platform: 'darwin',
    arch: 'x64',
    icon: RELEASE_OSX_IMAGE_ICON,
  }), next);
});
```

A windows build task may look something like this:

```
gulp.task('release-win', ['pre-release'], (next) => {
    electronPackager(_.extend(RELEASE_SETTINGS, {
        platform: 'win32',
        arch: 'all',
        icon: RELEASE_WIN_IMAGE_ICON,
    }), next);
});
```